# How can I move my photos from my iPad storage to my Windows 7 computer without a USB cable, AirDrop and iCloud?

Tags: ipad, windows, photos, file-transfer

I tried to select all the pictures, which is rather tedious, and upload them

1. to Google Drive, but if >100 pictures, Google Drive won't upload all the images.
2. to SendAnywhere, but this would take over an hour. However, I [cannot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/415979/20338) disable auto-lock on my iPad (iPadOS 13) (the maximum auto-lock period is 15 minutes), and whenever the iPad gets locked, uploads are stopped.

How can I move my photos from my iPad storage to my Windows 7 computer without a USB cable, AirDrop and iCloud?

Comment: What about another cloud service - dropbox or similar? 100 pics might fit into the 2GB that comes as default?  Dropbox supports background uploading too (https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/photos/camera-uploads-overview) - actually so do google drive (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190246/409922) with should overcome the "lock" case?

Comment: @MrR another cloud service is definitely welcome! The issue with Gdrive is that is has a bug cause the upload to be incomplete if trying to upload over  ca. 100 pics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way but you need to enable 1 thing in windows - it means - make a writable ftp server and connect to that server directly from ios app named „files” then you can do it. Only that you need to know how to configure ftp in windows (but that’s not a place I think for sharing thoughts about windows).

Comment: Ironically I was playing with FTP servers at the same time as I was asking the question about the iPad https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/642470/16704 so great timing!

Comment: You were lucky ? I wasn’t even looking at there...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the way to do it natively on the iPad so I used the application [Filemail](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filemail-send-large-files/id665033466) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324065237if_/https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filemail-send-large-files/id665033466)) (gratis), which:

1. allows users to select all photos+videos in one click (open Filemail then upload all pics/vids from there)
2. doesn't stop uploads after the iPad gets auto-locked.
3. doesn't require no registration to send up to 50 GB
4. doesn't have any ad.

[image]